# Mysql error 1049 prevents access to make corrections

Tags: mysql, django, self-hosting

I have developed a Django application and now find myself trying to host it on ubuntu 16.04. I'm following the DigitalOcean guides as far as possible.

I started a database for a Django application, created a user for the application, granted privileges to that user and then decided to dump the database for some reason (I think I was planning to ensure that the Django model could be migrated from scratch, but this was just before Christmas.)

If I try to log in to mysql I get Error 1049 (42000): Unknown database, and kicked back out to the shell - no interactive mysql.  How can I fix this?  It seems that mysql won't listen to me.

Comment: You dumped the database? or its tables?

Comment: I'm sorry, I "dropped" the database. And b. I discovered that the problem was in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf where I still had the dropped database identified as the database I wanted to use.  Once I deleted that entry from my.cnf, I am able to log on again.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not in mysql, but in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, where I still had a row that was implicitly loaded whenever I tried to interact with mysql. I deleted the row in my.cnf that said:

```
database='database_name'
```